# How to add a JFilechooser from another class to a JPanel that is in different class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

I am trying to add a `JFileChooser` from a `Main` class to `Splash` class panel. How can I do it?

```
public void openMenuFunc() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setApproveButtonText("Open");
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Open Design");
    fileChooser.setOpaque(false); 
}
```

This is the method in class PanelDisplay.java

```
public void addCenterPanel() {
   // I want to add that JFilechooser here 
   // leftCenterPanel.add(---Main.java class filechooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
}
```

Comment: JFileChooser is not a component that you _add_ to a container. Added components are generally permanently visible, e.g. a JLabel. JFileChooser, however, pops up on request with one of its showXDialogs. If you want to call the JFileChooser you have created in Main.java from Splash.java, filechooser has to be made a class variable which then could be referenced from Splash.java, or you have to create Splash from within Main and pass the filechooser as a parameter.

Comment: Why?  Context would help.  Why are you creating a `JFileChooser` in `Main`, but then trying to add it to `Splash`?  How are they related/what are their relationships?

Comment: Actually, Main.java class had a functions that are specific to the JFilechooser and Splash.Jav has panels where i need to add that JFilechooser

Comment: *"Actually.."* Be sure to add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of new comments.